# Failing unit test with mockito.mockStatic

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mockito

So, I'm writing a junit test and I can't seem te figure out why it is failing. I'm using Mockito.mockStatic in order to mock InetAddres.class. Running the unit tests all at once fails. Running them separately succeeds. I understand static blocks are initialized once. What I can't seem to figure out is why class Host is not reinitialized with every unit test. Any help is appreciated

J

Here is my code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


class HostTest {

    @Test
    void testLocalhost() {
        try (MockedStatic<InetAddress> inetAddressMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class)) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = Mockito.mock(InetAddress.class);
            Mockito.when(inetAddress.getHostName()).thenReturn("LOCALHOST");
            inetAddressMockedStatic.when(InetAddress::getLocalHost).thenReturn(inetAddress);
            assertThat(Host.getLOCALHOST()).isEqualTo("LOCALHOST");
            Mockito.reset(inetAddress);

        }
    }

    @Test
    void testIP() {
        try (MockedStatic<InetAddress> inetAddressMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class)) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = Mockito.mock(InetAddress.class);
            Mockito.when(inetAddress.getHostAddress()).thenReturn("127.0.0.1");
            inetAddressMockedStatic.when(InetAddress::getLocalHost).thenReturn(inetAddress);
            assertThat(Host.getIP()).isEqualTo("127.0.0.1");
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testUnkownHostExceptionIP() {
        try (MockedStatic<InetAddress> inetAddressMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class)) {
            inetAddressMockedStatic.when(InetAddress::getLocalHost).thenThrow(UnknownHostException.class);
            assertThat(Host.getIP()).isEqualTo("Unkown ip");
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testUnkownHostExceptionLocalhost() {
        try (MockedStatic<InetAddress> inetAddressMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class)) {
            inetAddressMockedStatic.when(InetAddress::getLocalHost).thenThrow(UnknownHostException.class);
            assertThat(Host.getLOCALHOST()).isEqualTo("Unkown hostname");

        }
    }
}




import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Host {

    private static String LOCALHOST;
    private static String IP;

    static {
        try {
            InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            LOCALHOST = localhost.getHostName();
            IP = localhost.getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOCALHOST = "Unkown hostname";
            IP = "Unkown ip";
        }
    }

    public static String getLOCALHOST() {
        return LOCALHOST;
    }

    public static String getIP() {
        return IP;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The static initializer is **only executed once**, when the class is loaded. This means it will only run for the first test case using the `Host` class.

In your example, once `testLocalhost` is run, the class is used in the line  `Host.getLOCALHOST()`, by which point its initializer has been executed. It never runs again throughout the rest of the unit tests.

If you switch the order of these test cases, you'll get a different result.

Judging by your test cases, there's a few things you could do to make the code match your expectations. Since the IP and the host name will change throughout the execution of your program, they shouldn't be static members set in the static initializer block.

1. Get rid of shared state. Setting aside concurrency and memory visibility, `static` members will be visible to all instances of the class. Omit the `static` keyword and make these into regular fields

   ```
   public class Host {

       private final String hostName;

       private final String ip;

       // Constructor, use this to build new instances
       public Host(String hostName, String ip) {
           this.hostName = hostName;
           this.ip = ip;
       }

       // No longer static, this is now an instance method
       public getHostName() {
           return this.hostName;
       }

       public getIp() {
           return this.ip;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build instances of your class, passing arguments to the constructor to customize its behaviour.

   ```
   // Host.getIp(); // If IP and host name can vary, don't make them static
   InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   // build a new instance of Host, provide the relevant data at construction time
   Host testedHost = new Host(localhost.getHostName(), localhost.getHostAddress());
   // call the instance method, this doesn't affect your other tests
   assertThat(testedHost.getIp()).is(someIp);
   // at this point, the Host instance you created may be garbage-collected to free memory (you don't need to do that yourself)
   ```

   Now every test case will be independent from the others. Just create a new instance of `Host` every time you need one.
3. Get rid of static mocks. notice how the `InetAddress` method invocations were moved outside the `Host` class. By passing them through the constructor, you make the code easier to test. [Inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) is achieved.

Instead of a public constructor, you could use a factory method. Bottom line is that if you want to have the class change its behaviour, it's usually better to create new instances and encapsulate any state.

Static classes and members are better suited for things like immutable contants that won't change throughout the execution of your program, or utility methods that don't rely on any internal state, i.e. [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).